# Why take the address of a reference give me a second rank pointer?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a more dangerous reinterpret_cast. The code blow doesn't seem to work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename TTo, typename TFrom>
TTo& horrible_cast(TFrom& from) {
    static_assert(sizeof(TFrom) == sizeof(TTo), "");
    union {
        TFrom* from = &from;  // error cannot convert
                              // from 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>> **' 
                              // to 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>> *' 
        TTo* to;
    };

    return *to;
    // return *reinterpret_cast<TTo*>(&from); this one works fine.
}


int main() {
    unique_ptr<int> u{ new int(3) };
    auto x = horrible_cast<int*>(u);
}
```

The `TFrom&` is deduced to be `unique_ptr<int>&`. But when take its address, it gives a `unique_ptr<int>**`. How can I fix it.
I'm using Visual studio 2017 community on window 8.1

Comment: My syntax highlighting shows that the  = &from variable is the TFrom* from declaration just before. That's pretty cool. Perhaps cooler that Storyteller picked it up so fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because of the anonymous union. Since the members of the union are injected into the surrounding scope, you have a `TFrom* from` variable that shadows the reference parameter `TFrom& from`.

So you are taking the address of a pointer in the initializer. Hence the whole double pointer shenanigans.

Beyond that, `reinterpret_cast` is already dangerous enough, so I feel your work in making this worse cast is redundant.